# Heuristic for using symbols rather than strings in J

Tags: j

While the real reason to use J's symbols (`s: ' Abe Bill Chad'`) rather than string arrays (`'Abe','Bill',:'Chad'`) or boxed lists of strings (`'Abe';'Bill';'Chad'`) is that it is the best solution (most efficient/convenient for man or machine), what is the rule of thumb for when to use symbols?

The [vocabulary page](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dsco.htm) for `s:` mentions efficient "searching, sorting, and comparisons." Do you start using symbols from the beginning if there's any chance you'll be searching, sorting, or comparing? Or do you only use symbols once you recognize that your code is working around the limitations of the other options? Or something a bit more nuanced in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience is that for most use cases symbol (`s:`) is not necessary to provide acceptable performance which matches the advice in the [section on Symbol in **J for C Programmers**](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help803/jforc/odds_and_ends.htm#_Toc191734566) that you use symbols if you find your program taking a lot of time matching strings. It also warns that:

> there is no way to tell the interpreter to free the resources for a
>   single string; this can be a problem if your symbol table is large and
>   changes dynamically.

For this reason the [Vocabulary page for Symbol on JWiki](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/sco) suggests symbols are most useful when:

- a limited number of strings appear repeatedly
- the set of symbols is known and unchanging